# Applying correct ZIP Code when Geocoding?

Tags: gps, geocoding, address, zip-codes

I need to batch geocode a set of addresses, some of them are missing the zip code causing the lat/lng to be placed incorrectly.

Is there a good way easily correct this?

I am using a few geocoders, GPS visualizer, Esri's US streets geocoder, and OSM geocoder in QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to find a easy solution to this since ZipCode boundaries are copyrighted. Your best solution is to download the most recent data from US-Census TIGER and intersect the addresses against the Zipcode-Tabulation-Areas. While these are not exact matching to USPS Zipcode areas (which update/adjust every 2 months) it should give you a good block to work from.
Otherwise you are looking at acquiring or working with an address-standardization and verification service which can help correct and add the missing information.

Comment: This is a good answer because it addresses the fact that [ZIP codes are not polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112899/how-to-get-the-bounding-coordinates-for-a-us-postalzip-code/13114578#13114578).